# Run Visual Studio on Microsoft Surface?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, tablet

It seems like Windows 8 is all about developers. But I didn't realize a small thing: can Visual Studio 2012 be launched on Intel-based Surface, like on my Win8-driven, Intel-based notebook?

Hardware specs are absolutely enough, the whole ideology looks like leading to "programming everywhere", there are a few simple IDEs even for iPad, we'll certainly have some dev tools when Ubuntu will be installed on Surface. But what about Visual Studio itself? Is there any info?

It's not very comfortable to develop everything on Surface, but sometimes the idea touches you in the bus, and it's nice to have a full-featured tool with all your current projects at your hand.

Comment: I think it's all about, Apple are making more money than us...

Comment: Well, I'd rather say, all about creating content (plus all iPad features as a bonus).

Comment: As already said - there is nothing stopping you running Visual Studio on non-Intel devices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say Windows 8 Pro, and devices like the Surface tablet, are all about being useful in any context. You probably won't code in visual studio while sitting on the couch, but you can certainly use the same machine (docked and attached to external monitor(s) and input devices) to code at a desk. It will run any application at any time, but the Metro UI is all about making 'tablet' contexts more efficient and usable.

Answer (score 12):

The Intel-based Surface can run arbitrary legacy Windows applications, including Visual Studio.
However, the screen may prove to be annoyingly small.

Comment: I do this with the Samsung tablet ... it's got HDMI out, so I can use a second monitor for VS and run directly on the device to test ... best of both worlds. :)

Comment: This actually works just fine on the Surface Pro, as long as you don't like to see too many toolbars. I like being able to code on the coach.

Comment: @Sayka: We are not talking about Galaxy devices; he's talking about a special device built for Build two years ago.  http://www.samsung.com/global/buildpc/index.html

Answer (score 4):

if it is a non-ARM machine you can run your visual studio on it. even existing samsung slate series 7 works fine.

it is decent for development when you dock it down with a keyboard, mouse and external monitor.

Answer (score 4):

The PRO version is definitely what you want/need if you want it to act like a cross between an actual laptop (run normal programs and do programming) and a tablet (when detached from the keyboard/dock etc.

http://www.microsoft.com/Surface/en-US/surface-with-windows-rt/help-me-choose

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the biggest stumbling blocks may turn out to be available hard drive space. As a rough guide VS 2012 Ultimate seems to require about 10gb , VS Community can require about 20gb of space.

[visual studio 2012 download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30678)

It won't allow you to install to an SD card, a mount point will only give you as much space as you already have available on the hard drive.

You'll need to have a big enough hard drive to fit the OS and the development tools on there.